# PageSpeed Insights reports over 100s Main Thread Work on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have this website, that I think loads **really** fast and is nicely optimized, but whenever I run it through PageSpeed, it receives a horrible score on Mobile only?

[image]

With "Minimize main thread work" being the main one, spending allegedly 124 seconds on Rendering?

[image]

I've tried debugging it in DevTools, with the Performance tab, but even with CPU slowdown and slow 3G, I can't get it to show any problems. The long tasks in the screenshot are all related to Extensions I have installed in Chrome.

[image]

The JavaScript is run through Babel with the "@babel/preset-env" preset and then minified afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this is what threw PageSpeed off:

```
.hero-image.animated {
    animation: animatedBackground var(--hero-animated-duration) linear;
    background-position: bottom right;
}
```

Removing the animation, fixed the issue with mobile pages scoring really low.

Answer (score 0):

From Colombia you have a mobile version performance of 82 in PageSpeed

First Contentful Paint
1,7 s
Time to Interactive
3,1 s
Speed Index
3,3 s
Total Blocking Time
30 ms
Renderizado del mayor elemento con contenido
4,5 s
Cumulative Layout Shift
0,017

the result is very good.